# Creating a list with non-consecutive items - Especially within exam Class

Tags: lists, exam, parts

I would like to make a list that is numbered however I want it to be, not just consecutively.

Specifically, within the exam class, how could I go to question #10 immediately after question #5? Or part (c) after part (a)?

Thank you very much!

```
\documentclass{exam}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question Number 1

\question Number 50

\begin{parts}

\part Part a

\part Part g

\end{parts}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the counters `question` and `partno`:

```
\documentclass{exam}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question Number 1

\setcounter{question}{49}
\question Number 50

\begin{parts}

\part Part a

\setcounter{partno}{6}
\part Part g

\end{parts}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]